# Excel can not Save As with Arabic

Tags: excel

Situation:
The software application I am using uploads data using a .txt file. The application supports Arabic using UTF-8.

Problem:
I create an excel document with the appropriate columns and rows and enter an Arabic value into one of the cells. When I click the Save As > Tab Delimitated Text (.txt) format, Excel saves the file however the Arabic originally in the file is replaced with "*_*_".

Question:
How can I create a .txt file in Excel that properly saves the Arabic text? Is it possible?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can not do this with saving as because the export of the Arabic characters is not supported by Excel the SOLUTION is on Excel type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all text then go to notepad or wordpad and paste all the selection there.